# Determine when app was foregrounded from status bar tap

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

If I have an app that's doing something that causes the double status bar to appear on iOS (such as a phone call (green bar) or using the microphone (orange bar)), the user can tap on that to bring the noted app to the foreground.

Is there any way for that suddenly foregrounded app to be aware that it was launched via that tap instead of just via the normal app icon or task switcher?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: There's no such functionality available, but wouldn't the app in question know if it was performing some activity in the background to cause the status bar to grow like this? I'm pretty sure your application should know if it's in a state where the user is talking on the phone or recording audio.